# Amazon SES as an inbound smtp proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, smtpproxy

Has anyone tried to use SES as a spam removal service for a self-hosted e-mail server where port 25 is blocked? In this case, I'd like SES to handle spam, but then I'd like to route the message to *smtp:mydomain.net:2525* instead of the normal port 25.

I've seen arithmetric's SES Forwarder, but it uses the SES e-mail sender for relaying the message, which will hit the same issue with delivery failure when it tries to use standard port 25 to get to my MTA.

If you haven't tried it, any suggestions on a node.js library that could help with taking a message from S3 and deliverying it to an MX that's not listening on 25?